# Oracle- How We know that no field update by update command

Tags: oracle

I am looking to find, if I executed update command to update single record in oracle with some parameter and all parameter value are same in fields value. technically no value updated in that record database.

in this situation. do I get any information that told me that record is not changed

Like Employee table have two column FirstName, SecondName and have one record 
'John','Smith'

I executed following  update command like \n

```
update Employee (FirstName,LastName) Values('John','Smith');
```

Comment: That is not valid UPDATE syntax

Answer (score 5):

Oracle, in the example you provided (which is syntactically wrong and will throw an error), did in fact update 1 row. You can check `SQL%ROWCOUNT` and it will say `1`. It doesn't care that it was the same value, it only cares that there was a record there, no WHERE clause, and it had to update it. So it did.

And really... this makes sense. Why read each record before updating it to see if it's going to update to the same thing. It's quicker to just write where it's told to write and move on.

The only way to prevent Oracle from ACTUALLY updating the row is to add a WHERE clause to prevent it that matches the values you are updating with:

```
 UPDATE yourtable 
 SET FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Smith' 
 WHERE FirstName <> 'John' AND LastName <> 'Smith';
```

Now if you check `SQL%ROWCOUNT` you will get 0.

Updating to add: [Really good write up here on dba.stackexchange.com about this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126233/how-to-find-the-number-of-rows-changed-by-an-update-statement-in-oracle)